# Place textview left and right above a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have following relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But this is not giving me the result I expected
I want to achieve the following:

tv1--------------tv2
|------Button------|

So, I want textview1 to start at the left corner of the button and textview2 to end at the right edge of the button.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1" />
</RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center" 
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button inside your relative layout. And then add this to the button xml properties -

```
android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
```

For tv1 textview, add -

```
android:layout_alignLeft="button1"
```

for tv2 textview, add -

```
android:layout_alignRight="button1"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv2"/>
 </RelativeLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you need to set either android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv2" for tv1 or android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv1" for tv2 to stop overlapping each other.